Encountering problem using react-windrose-chart; Uncaught Error: over 360 or under 0
I am experiencing an issue with the wind direction values in my React application. Despite fetching data from an API endpoint, which ensures that wind direction values are within the range of 0 to 360 degrees, I encounter the error stating that the values are either over 360 or under 0.
My suspicion is that the error may be originating from the calculateWindRose function. Further investigation into this function's implementation may help identify the cause of the issue.
The error suggests that wind direction values are either over 360 or under 0, despite the fetched data being expected to comply with the range.
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-windrose-chart";
import { calculateWindRose } from "react-windrose-chart";

const RoseChart = () => {
  const [roseData,setRoseData] = useState([]);
    
  useEffect(() =>{
      fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
      try{
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/weather');
          const jsonData = await response.json();
          setRoseData(jsonData);
      }catch (error) {
          console.log('Error fetching data', error);
      }
  };
  
  const data = {
    direction: [roseData.map((r)=>r.avgWindDir )],
    speed:  [roseData.map((r)=>r.avgWindSpeed)]
  }
  
  const windRoseData = calculateWindRose(data);

  return(
    <div>
      <Chart
        chartData={windRoseData.chartData}
        columns={windRoseData.columns}
        responsive={true}
        legendGap={10}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default RoseChart;

I've tried numerous approaches to resolve this issue, but unfortunately, none have been successful so far. I've meticulously examined all the values both manually and through console logging of the fetched data, yet I couldn't identify any anomalies. Additionally, I've thoroughly inspected the database to ensure there are no issues with the stored values. Despite these efforts, the error persists.

Please share a working stackblitz with some sample data for debugging the issue!
